# How to retrieve a data from SQLite and view it in a TextView?

Tags: java, android, database, xcode, sqlite

I am trying to retrieve my email from my SQLiteDbHelper and view it in a TextView in another activity after I click sign in, using the WelcomeActivity or splash activity since I only want it to be view for 4 seconds, but idk whats the problem when I sign in it crashes me out.

**DataBaseHelper.java**

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    private DataBaseHelper dbHelper;
    public static SQLiteDatabase m_db;
    public static final String DB_NAME = "users.dbHelper";
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String TABLE_USERS = "users";
    public static final String COLUMN_EMAIL = "email";
    public static final String COLUMN_PASSWORD = "password";
    public static final String [] ALL_COLUMNS = {COLUMN_EMAIL, COLUMN_PASSWORD};
    public static final String SQL_CREATE =
            "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_USERS + " (" +
                    COLUMN_EMAIL + " STRING PRIMARY KEY, " +
                    COLUMN_PASSWORD + " STRING);";
    public static final String SQL_DROP = "DROP TABLE " + TABLE_USERS;
    public DataBaseHelper(@Nullable Context context)
    {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE);
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {
        db.execSQL(SQL_DROP);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    //---opens the database---
    public DataBaseHelper open() throws SQLException
    {
        m_db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    //---closes the database---
    public void close()
    {
        if (m_db != null)
            m_db.close();
        if (dbHelper != null)
            dbHelper.close();
    }

    // Inserting in database
    public boolean insert(String email, String password)
    {
        m_db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("email", email);
        contentValues.put("password", password);
        long ins = m_db.insert(TABLE_USERS, null, contentValues);
        if (ins == -1) return false;
        else return true;
    }

    // Checking if email exists
    public boolean checkEmail(String COLUMN_EMAIL)
    {
        m_db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = m_db.rawQuery("select * from TABLE_USERS where COLUMN_EMAIL=?",
        new String[]{COLUMN_EMAIL});
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) return false;
        else return true;
    }

    // Checking the email and password
    public boolean checkEmailPassword(String COLUMN_EMAIL, String COLUMN_PASSWORD)
    {
        m_db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = m_db.rawQuery("select * from TABLE_USERS where COLUMN_EMAIL=?
        and COLUMN_PASSWORD=?", new String[]{COLUMN_EMAIL, COLUMN_PASSWORD});
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) return true;
        else return false;
    }

    public String getEmail(String COLUMN_EMAIL)
    {
        m_db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = m_db.query(TABLE_USERS, new String[]{COLUMN_EMAIL}, null, null,
        null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String user = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_EMAIL));
        cursor.close();
        return user;
    }
}
```

**WelcomeActivity.Java**

```
public class WelcomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 4000;
    private DataBaseHelper db;
    private SQLiteDatabase m_db;
    private TextView tvEmail2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

        db = new DataBaseHelper(this);

        TextView tvEmail = findViewById(R.id.tvEmail2);
        String email = db.getEmail(DataBaseHelper.COLUMN_EMAIL);
        String user = email;

        tvEmail.setText(Users.class.getEm);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this, EthicsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }
}
```

**Users.java**

```
public class Users
{
    private String email;
    private String password;
    public Users() {}

    public Users(String email, String password)
    {
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEmail()
    {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email)
    {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword()
    {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password)
    {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Users{" +
                "email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", password='" + password + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

What do you guys think about this?
I am trying to retrieve my email from my SQLiteDbHelper and view it in a TextView in another activity after I click sign in, using the WelcomeActivity or splash activity since I only want it to be view for 4 seconds, but idk whats the problem when I sign in it crashes me out.

Comment: Can you please let me know the logcat?

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: idk if its an error now, the activity is closing and does not move to a new activity as intented

Comment: Post the logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you have a number of issues.

The line `tvEmail.setText(Users.class.getEm);` won't compilem I believe that instead want `tvEmail.setText(user);`  or `tvEmail.setText(email);` (you don't need to have both `email` and `user` Strings having the same value).

Assuming that EthicsActivity is a valid working activity, and that there is an appropriate **activity** entry in the manifest **AndroidManifest.xml** then the issue is that you would get an error along the lines of :-

```
11-10 19:56:12.863 1170-1170/so53240174.so53240174 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{so53240174.so53240174/so53240174.so53240174.WelcomeActivity}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
        at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:418)
        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
        at so53240174.so53240174.DataBaseHelper.getEmail(DataBaseHelper.java:96)
        at so53240174.so53240174.WelcomeActivity.onCreate(WelcomeActivity.java:25)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is saying that the Cursor is empty so you cannot get any data from it and it happens at the line **`String user = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_EMAIL));`** which is in the **getEmail** method as indicated by the line in the log :-

> ```
> at so53240174.so53240174.DataBaseHelper.getEmail(DataBaseHelper.java:96)
> ```

The reason why this is happening is that a) there are no rows in the **users** table and b) that the Cursor **moveToFirst** method's result isn't checked. Instead an assumption is made that it will always move to the first row in the Cursor.

Instead of the **getEmail** method being :-

```
public String getEmail(String COLUMN_EMAIL)
{
    m_db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = m_db.query(TABLE_USERS, new String[]{COLUMN_EMAIL}, null, null,
            null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst(); //<<<<<<<<<< WRONG
    String user = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_EMAIL));
    cursor.close();
    return user;
}
```

It could be :-

```
public String getEmail(String COLUMN_EMAIL) {
    String user = "No Email Found."; //<<<<<<<<<< Default value in case of empty table
    m_db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = m_db.query(TABLE_USERS, new String[]{COLUMN_EMAIL}, null, null,
            null, null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) { //<<<<<<<<<< checks result of the move
        user = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_EMAIL));
    }
    cursor.close();
    return user;
}
```

Of course applying this fix, unless a row is added to the **users** table will always result in the TextView displaying **No Email Found**. If there are multiple rows then it will display the email from one of the rows, not necessarily a specific row.

Adding the line `db.insert("fred@fredmail.com","1234567890");` before the value is retrieved using the call to the **getEmail** results in **fred@fredmail.com** being displayed in the TextView.

Comment: That was helpful sir! but now i have stumbled into a new problem, it is as you said it will retrieve the last username entered, but that's not the case i want my text view in welcome activity capture the email that was entered in the sign in activity, i want to retrieve that for every user i am trying to enter, right now i can only retrieve the last registered user email no matter what other users i am signing in with, do you have an idea how to do that?

Comment: The way that StackOverflow is meant to work, is that you ask a question for each issue you are having, so what you ask should be raised as a new question.

Comment: I apologze sir!